# Using NavigationManager NavigateTo forceload in Blazor server doesn't reload the entire index

Tags: c#, .net, navigation, blazor, identity

Creating dotnet Blazor Server app that uses MS Identity services.  When user registers and logins, the app sends them a razor component that adds additional user info not kept in MS Identity - they must complete this to continue.  I'm using Identity auth & roles in both navbar and index page redirects.  When I run this in the user form (razor component)...

```
navMgr.NavigateTo("/", forceLoad: true);
```

It doesn't even leave the razor component which is embedded in Index.razor.

What I would like is that this form completion would completely refresh to "/" for that user (as if they just logged in).  Do I have to log the user out to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to fix the problem in the index.razor page. Used consumer and disabled in my @if().

```
protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
{
    authstate = await GetAuthenticationStateAsync.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
    authuser = authstate.User.Identity.Name;
    if (authuser != null)
    {
        user = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(authuser);
        consumer = await userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, "Consumer");
        disabled = await userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, "Disabled");
    }
}
```